# Erro de Java.lang.String cannot be cast to , quando capturo os dados no Jcomobox para salvar

Tags: java, cast

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho o evento do botão salva, quando eu clico para salvar, aparece a seguinte : `Java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.nomedopacote.modelo.Funcionario`

- cbNomeUsuario - É nome da Jcomobox que estão pegando uma List Funcionario .

  ```
      usuario.setFuncionario((Funcionario) cbNomeUsuario.getSelectedItem());
  ```

Um erro de cast, alguém pode me ajudar ?

Quero pegar o retorno ou seja o ID do funcionario para guardar no banco.

Salvar no banco normal :
objeto.getFuncionario().getId();

Comment: Se você mostrar sua classe `Funcionário` fica mais fácil te ajudar.

Answer (score 1):

Sua chamada `(Funcionario) cbNomeUsuario.getSelectedItem()` está tentando converter para o tipo `Funcionario` um objeto do tipo `String`, que está sendo retornado por `cbNomeUsuario.getSelectedItem()`. São tipos incompatíveis.

De fato, seu código sugere que você está querendo guardar um objeto do tipo `Funcionario` retornado por um método que retorna somente o nome do usuário (`cbNomeUsuario.getSelectedItem()`).

Corrija o método `getSelectedItem()`, ou então poste o código do mesmo na sua pergunta para tentarmos entender o que pode estar acontecendo.

Answer (score 1):

Não vi a declaração e inicialização da sua ComboBox mas a classe [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) é parametrizada. Logo você pode declarar algo do tipo: `JComboBox<Funcionario> combo = new JComboBox<Funcionario>();` ou `JComboBox<Funcionario> combo = new JComboBox<>()`;

E fazer a inserção dos itens normalmente: `combo.addItem(...);` utilizando os objetos da classe `Funcionario` sem precisar converter para `String`.

Caso não possa mudar isso, você pode usar o método `getSelectedIndex()` e acessar o objeto de sua coleção.

E Assim como o Piovezan disse, você está realizando um cast de `Funcionario` em um objeto do tipo `String`. O que gera o erro detectado.